# Select Case with String

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting frustrated with using Select Case and a string to compare.

I just need to check if somebody makes a comment or just go on by scanning different objects.

So I read in the statement and check if there is a part number coming in (always starting with a N) or if not so I know where to go next.

Since there are three cases that could happen next I cannot take a `if temp = Left(temp, 1) = "N"`.

Where is my mistake?

```
            temp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Would you like to make a comment?" & vbCrLf & "If not please continue with next scan. ", Title:="Comment or go on", Type:=2)
            Select Case temp

                Case Is = Left(temp, 1) = "N"
                'New scan - next number got scanned
                    MsgBox ("Controlmessage - N Case")
                    i = i + 1
                    .Cells(i, "D").Select
                    temp = ""

            End Select
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Main()

    temp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Would you like to make a comment?" & vbCrLf & "If not please continue with next scan. ", Title:="Comment or go on", Type:=2)

    Select Case UCase(Left(temp, 1))
        Case "N"
            MsgBox "N"
        Case "C"
            MsgBox "C"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "something else"
    End Select

End Sub
```